# Why imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: doesn't work?

Tags: ios, image, cgimage

This is my question:

I want to rotate my image when I got the degree it should rotate.

And my code is here

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
UIImage *originalImage = imageView.image;
CGAffineTransform transform = imageView.transform;

        if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(transform, CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI_2))) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
        } else if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(transform, CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI))) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
        } else if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(transform, CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI_2 * 3))) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
        } else if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(transform, CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI * 2))) {
            image = originalImage; // UIImageOrientationUp
        }
```

As I hope , the `image` will show as rotated. But after rotating, this images is still what it was. It means the method `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` didn't work.

Some one can tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: You first `UIImage *image = imageView.image;` has no effect other than to declare 'image' which you then set to the result of the transform.  But, you don't do anything with the result.  Nathan Ou has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
```

to get the handle of imageView.image, and you've set your changed image for (UIImage*)image which is just a reference of imageView.image.So if you want imageView.image to be change, you should set imageView.image again to make it change

add this in the back after your codes

```
imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set the image again (after all that code)

```
imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you will need to fundamentally understand.  When you get a pointer to another object, and then set that pointer to something else, it doesn't affect the original object.  Think of it this way:

```
Lunch *myLunch = myFriend.CurrentLunch;
```

This means that your lunch is current your friend's lunch.

```
myLunch = new MisoRamen();
```

Now your lunch is a different lunch.

```
myLunch.InsertWeirdSauce();
```

You just inserted a sauce into your own lunch, while your friend's lunch remains safe.  If you want to change your friend's lunch you have to do this.

```
Lunch *newLunch = new MisoRamen();
newLunch.InsertWeirdSauce();
myFriend.CurrentLunch = newLunch;
```

Now your friend will gasp in shock as he/she eats a lunch with weird sauce in it.

Comment: Ah, I think this is the same as Nathan Ou's answer, but not as clear.